# Terraform: invalid characters in heredoc anchor

Tags: terraform

I am trying to use a multiline string in the `provisioner "remote-exec"` block of my terraform script.  Yet whenever I use the `EOT` syntax as outlined in the documentation and various examples I get an error that complains about having: `invalid characters in heredoc anchor`.

Here is an example of a simple `provisioner "remote-exec"` that received this error (both types of EOT receive this error when attempted separately):

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    << EOT 
    echo hi 
    EOT,

    << EOT 
    echo \
    hi 
    EOT,
  ]
}
```

**Update:** Here is the working solution, read carefully if you are having this issue because terraform is very picky when it comes to EOF:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [<<EOF

   echo foo
   echo bar

  EOF
  ]
}
```

Note that if you want to use EOF all the commands you use in a `provisioner "remote-exec"` block must be inside the EOF.  You cannot have both EOF and non EOF its one or the other.

The first line of EOF must begin like this, and you cannot have any whitespace in this line after `<<EOF` or else it will complain about having `invalid characters in heredoc anchor`:

```
  inline = [<<EOF
```

Your EOF must then end like this with the `EOF` at the same indentation as the `]`

```
  EOF
  ]
```

Comment: please accept an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Heredocs in Terraform are particularly funny about the surrounding whitespace.

Changing your example to the following seems to get rid of the heredoc specific errors:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [<<EOF
echo hi
EOF,
<<EOF
echo \
hi
EOF
  ]
}
```

You shouldn't need multiple heredocs in here at all though as the inline array is a list of commands that should be ran on the remote host. Using a heredoc with commands across multiple lines should work fine for you:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [<<EOF
echo foo
echo bar
EOF
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yep that worked great.  Its really annoying how picky EOF format is in terraform.  That if I want to use EOF format then all my commands in the `provisioner "remote-exec"` block have to be in EOF.  Whats really terrible how NONE of this is explained on the terraform documentation in the one section that actually mentions EOF.  Like if you are going to have part of your software be **extremely** picky you should at least give an example in your documentation to make people aware of this.

Comment: Actually as it turns out the terraform documentation is flat out wrong!  They mention using `EOT` format (which doesn't work).  The working format is EOF as @ydaetskcoR working example uses `EOF` which is not mentioned at all in the documentation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax.html

Comment: the heck is the diff between `EOF` and `EOT` format?

Comment: There's no difference, you can use FOOBAR if you want, the issue is around the surrounding whitespace. EOF is just a more standard heredoc anchor so that's what I used.

Answer (score 2):

The here-document end-delimiter has a comma (`,`) at the end. That's not allowed.

Try this instead:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    <<EOT 
    echo hi
EOT
    ,
    <<EOT 
    echo \
    hi 
EOT
    ,
  ]
}
```

I'm unaware of the syntax requirements of the file, but a here-document end-delimiter needs to match the word used at its start.

Also, usually (in shells), the delimiter needs to come first on the line (no whitespace in front).

In fact, the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax.html) says this:

> Multiline strings can use shell-style "here doc" syntax, with the
>   string starting with a marker like `<<EOT` and then the string ending
>   with `EOT` on a line of its own. The lines of the string and the end
>   marker must not be indented.

Comment: Nah, I tried that after you said that "usually (in shells), the delimiter needs to come first on the line (no whitespace in front)." So no luck there. I even tried removing all the whitespace from the EOT lines except for the space in between `echo hi` with no changes.

Comment: @AlexCohen I'm wondering if it's a problem with the here-doc or with the surrounding document? Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Nope it works fine without the EOT stuff, see my update in the original question for a detailed example.